# Route the process based on conditions

Tags: mule, dataweave

Am trying to route the process based on input payload.

input:

```
{
    "data": {
        "schema": "rWdXQ7M38dwTJ8Ro29S8PQ",
        "payload": {            
            "ChangeEventHeader": {
                "changeType": "CREATE",
                "changedFields": [


                ],
                "Name": "Case",
                "recordIds": [
                    "a77V00000000vI4IAA"
                ]
            },
            
            "Last_Month_Work_Billed_RS__c": 0.0
        },
        "event": {
            "replayId": 10198245
        }
    },
    "channel": "/data/Job__ChangeEvent"
}
```

I am using choice connector in mule 4

the data weave expression am using is below

`payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType == "CREATE" & Name != " "`

It gives me error. how can i achieve this through expressions?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 2):

Please, provide error what you have. Try

```
payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType ~= "CREATE" and payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.Name != " " and payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.Name?
```

Comment: How can i check whether Name filed is present in ChangeEventHeader or not ?

Comment: Added payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.Name? to the logicla expression. So ithis Name should be always presented

Answer (score 1):

Dataweave dos not understand the ampersand symbol as a logical operator (in this case, 'and').
Also, you should add the full path to the 'Name' property.

Use the following dataweave expression:

```
payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.changeType == "CREATE" and payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader.Name != " "
```

Dataweave logical operators are described here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-operators#logical_operators

Comment: How can i check whether Name filed is present in ChangeEventHeader or not ?

Comment: You can use the following dataweave expression: `isEmpty(payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader)`: returns true if ChangeEventHeader does not exist. Otherwise, false. If you want check if this element exists, you can use the following expression: `!isEmpty(payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader)`. This expression returns true when the element exists.

Comment: You can also check it that way: `payload.data.payload.ChangeEventHeader?`. This expression returns true only if the element is present.

Answer (score 1):

You can also explore this syntax:

```
payload..changeType[0] == "CREATE" and !isEmpty(payload..Name[0])
```

`isEmpty(<expression>)`: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-isempty

Comment: `isEmpty()` wouldn't check the `!= " "` case... use `isBlank()` instead